# How to Sort Org-Mode Headings Without Losing Metadata in Emacs?

Tags: org-mode, sorting

I am trying to write an elisp function that can sort org headings and move the subtree with the headings while preserving the file metadata.

Here is the version information for Emacs and Org and the OS I use:

- GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.38, cairo version 1.17.8) of 2023-09-11.
- Org mode version 9.6.6
- Arco Linux

This is the format of the headings in my file:

```
#+TITLE: Prototypes
#+AUTHOR: foghorn
#+DATE: 2024-02-12

** CNC PARTNUMBER :CNC:

- DESCRIPTION: 
- MATERIAL: 
- ORDER NUMBER: 
- STATUS: 
- PRINTED: 
- UPDATED:

** WELDING PARTNUMBER :WELDING:

- DESCRIPTION: 
- MATERIAL: 
- ORDER NUMBER: 
- STATUS: 
- PRINTED: 
- UPDATED:

** MACHINESHOP PARTNUMBER :MACHINESHOP:

- DESCRIPTION: 
- MATERIAL: 
- ORDER NUMBER: 
- STATUS: 
- PRINTED: 
- UPDATED:
```

The part numbers vary in length but always start with the letter `Y`. Daily, I track various parts through the factory and update this org document. The TODO keyword is the location of the part in the factory, and it changes frequently. I like keeping the same headings grouped together as a quick way to scan for a work center bottleneck. There are 20+ TODO states used.

When sorting, I would like all the information beneath a heading to follow along, but Org says there are no items to sort when I try using `C-c ^`.

The ultimate result desired is:

```
#+TITLE: Prototypes
#+AUTHOR: foghorn
#+DATE: 2024-02-12

** CNC PARTNUMBER :CNC:

- DESCRIPTION: 
- MATERIAL: 
- ORDER NUMBER: 
- STATUS: 
- PRINTED: 
- UPDATED:

** MACHINESHOP PARTNUMBER :MACHINESHOP:

- DESCRIPTION: 
- MATERIAL: 
- ORDER NUMBER: 
- STATUS: 
- PRINTED: 
- UPDATED:

** WELDING PARTNUMBER :WELDING:

- DESCRIPTION: 
- MATERIAL: 
- ORDER NUMBER: 
- STATUS: 
- PRINTED: 
- UPDATED:
```

And if there are multiple headings with the same TODO, then the sorting flows left-to-right after the TODO keyword. The six status objects under each heading are the same for every heading and are sorted as they need to be but they are what I want to move with the headings during the sorting.

So, I have the following function, and it sorts the headings and moves the subtree just fine but always deletes the metadata I have at the top of the file, e.g., `#+TITLE:`, `#+AUTHOR:`, `#+DATE:`. I run it by pasting it into and evaluating the scratch buffer.

```lisp
(defun simple-sort-org-headings ()
  "A simplified function to sort all headings in the current buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((headings (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'headline
                   (lambda (headline)
                     (let ((begin (org-element-property :begin headline))
                           (end (org-element-property :end headline)))
                       (buffer-substring-no-properties begin end))))))
    ;; Sort the headings
    (setq headings (sort headings 'string<))
    ;; Clear the buffer and insert sorted headings
    (erase-buffer)
    (dolist (heading headings)
      (insert heading "\n"))))
```

I am at a loss for how to preserve the metadata. I had hoped this would work.

```lisp
(defun sort-org-headings-by-todo-and-preserve-metadata ()
  "Sort Org mode headings by TODO state and alphabetically within each TODO category, preserving file metadata."
  (interactive)
  (unless (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
    (error "Not in an Org mode buffer."))
  ;; Find the end of the metadata section.
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (let ((metadata-end (if (re-search-forward "^\\* " nil t)
                          (match-beginning 0)
                        (point-max))))
    ;; Collect headings after metadata.
    (let ((headings (org-map-entries
                     (lambda ()
                       (let* ((element (org-element-at-point))
                              (todo (or (org-element-property :todo-keyword element) ""))
                              (title (or (org-element-property :raw-value element) ""))
                              (begin (org-element-property :begin element))
                              (end (org-element-property :end element))
                              (text (buffer-substring-no-properties begin end)))
                         ;; Ensure TODO and title are strings for safe comparison.
                         (list (concat todo " " title) text)))
                     nil (list (point) (point-max)) t)))
      ;; Sort the headings.
      (setq headings (sort headings (lambda (a b) (string< (car a) (car b)))))
      ;; Delete the old content, preserving metadata.
      (delete-region metadata-end (point-max))
      ;; Reinsert sorted headings.
      (goto-char metadata-end)
      (dolist (heading headings)
        (insert (cadr heading) "\n")))))
```

This will preserve metadata because it does not seem to do anything to the file. I cannot discern any changes, much less any sorting. Also, this produces no errors.

I am yanking the metadata before sorting and pasting it afterward. This function would help me remove that step from the process.

Does anybody have any advice or suggestions on how to modify my elisp function to sort org-mode headings and preserve metadata at the top of the file? Specifically, I'm looking for insights on how to prevent the metadata from being deleted during the sorting process.

Comment: Your question is not completely clear to me, but can't you just use `org-sort`? Just make sure that your cursor is placed before the first heading (it works fine here).

Comment: What @dalanicolai said: Do `C-h f org-sort` to get more info.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: `org-sort` worked on my Windows machine but failed on the Linux machine. I do not know why but I will attempt once again when home. I always figured `org-sort` should work but couldn’t get to do so.